# Simple, free project management software

Tags: project-management, collaboration

I'm not actually certain that what I'm looking for is called project management software.  I want something very simple.  Suppose three people are working on a project together.  The software should give them a place in the cloud to share files; and the collaborators should send messages to the other group members, which can all be viewed in the cloud, in a place associated with that particular project.  (Since I might have other projects going with other people.)  I should be able to choose a setting that sends me an email when someone uploads a file or writes me a message.  The email should contain the content of the message, and the uploaded file should be attached to the email.  The advantage of this method over plain old email, and attachments, and a shared dropbox folder, is that if I want to look for an old message, I don't have to sort through all my email -- I can just go to that project online, and see ALL the messages that have been exchanged as part of that project.

It would be a plus if the uploaded files could have tags.

Comment: look at  asana.com

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Alfresco](https://www.alfresco.com/alfresco-community-download) document management system or [Nuxeo](https://www.nuxeo.com/products/content-management-platform/).
You can use alfresco share for collaborative project management or adapt another UI application (I'm biased here) like [OpenESDH](https://github.com/OpenESDH/OpenESDH-UI), both of which require the alfresco repository to work.

Answer (score 1):

The first option that comes to my mind is Trello. It has a Kanban methodology. Imagine a board where you can move any step, or post it from a "to do" column or to a review one.

https://trello.com

There is a free version, but in order to share files, you need to pay some fee.

Another option is:

https://freedcamp.com

You can look for alternatives like them.

You still can save space on your projects, for example, posting a link to a OneDrive hosted file or another cloud-based Drive instead of using this site's space.

Comment: Thumbs up for freedcamp.com In your case I think is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

1.Smartsheet- Smartsheet is the best in cloud based support tech that track and manage projects. 
2.Freshdesk- project management software which is also cloud based

Answer (score 1):

You could also check out [Teamhood](https://teamhood.com/use-cases/project-management/). It is a visual project management tool, that offers what you are looking for and a little extra. The good thing is, the extra features are not overcrowding the view if you are not using them.

Also, it is free for up to 5 users.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [height](https://height.app/) it has many features: lists, tasks, chat in context, kanban, calendar, REST API...

And in addition to many integrations: Zapier, GitHub, Slack...

I think it is a very complete (and very attractive) solution and you will surely find the [environment](https://height.app/workflows) in which you are most comfortable.

There are macOS and Windows apps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, it sounds like you're seeking a streamlined collaboration platform that seamlessly integrates file sharing, messaging, and email notifications. Based on your requirements, I recommend considering Slack for your project management needs. Slack provides dedicated channels for each project, serving as a centralized space in the cloud for file sharing and communication.

With Slack, you can easily track messages and file uploads related to a specific project without cluttering your email inbox. The ability to receive email notifications with message content and attached files ensures that you stay updated on project activities, even when you're not actively logged into the platform.

What sets Slack apart is its intuitive interface, real-time messaging features, and robust search functionality. You can effortlessly revisit past conversations, eliminating the need to sift through your email for specific project-related information.